# Error when i try to save a decimal in my edit form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, model, .net-6.0

i have this field in my model :

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Il budget é richiesto")]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [Display(Name = "Budget")]
    public decimal ContactBudget { get; set; }
```

when i save in my creation page the value 1000 all works fine.

when i try to edit, the value showed inside the textbox is not longer 1000 but 1000,00

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="ContactBudget" class="control-label"></label>
            <input type="text" asp-for="ContactBudget" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="ContactBudget" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
```

and when i try to save i got this error:

```
The field Budget must be a number.
```

if i try to change in 1000.00 i got thi other error :

```
The value '1000.00' is not valid for Budget.
```

but if i rewrite 1000 i can save the form.

What to do to allow also the value 1000,00 ?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Serge, i added your code :     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Il budget é richiesto")]
        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        [Display(Name = "Budget")]
        [Precision(18, 2)]
        public decimal ContactBudget { get; set; }  after i did add-migration and update-database, but the problem is still there, when i try to edit i see 1000,00 and if i try to save i got the following error model : The field Budget must be a number.

Comment: Did you try to use . instead of , ? 1000.00 ?

Comment: Hi, thanks again for your answer, i hope i will find the solution.. if i try with 1000.00 i got this error "The value '1000.00' is not valid for Budget." .. i acutally  wanto to be able to save price like 192,82 or 1000,00 .. hope you will be able to help!

Comment: Did you check the database column using management studio? is the column is changed ?

Comment: yes i did update database and all is changed : type donnee :decimal (18, 2)

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework translates the Decimal variable type as Decimal(18, 0) in SQL.

so change your property attribute

```
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [Display(Name = "Budget")]
    [Precision(18, 2)]
    public decimal ContactBudget { get; set; }
```

and made migration. DatType currency just adds a currency sign.

if you still have problem with comma instead of dot  then try to replace type text with type number

```
<input type="number" asp-for="ContactBudget" class="form-control" />
```

or you can try to use this data annotation instead

```
[Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,2)")]
public decimal ContactBudget { get; set; }
```

Comment: so, any example that actually works? thanks